# insertSubview:belowSubview: in UITableViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell`s that are swipable. When a cell is swiped, I want a view to be visible (revealed) underneath that cell. Here's the code that I have:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

_cellBack = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
_cellBack.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.tableView insertSubview:_cellBack belowSubview:cell];

for (int i = 0; i < [self.tableView subviews].count; i++) {
    UIView *v = [[self.tableView subviews] objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([v isEqual:_cellBack]) {
        NSLog(@"cellBack %d", i);
    }
    if ([v isEqual:cell]) {
        NSLog(@"cell %d", i);
    }
}
```

In the `for` loop, I check to see if the views' indexes are as I expect, and indeed they are; `_cellBack` has an index that is one less than `cell`'s index.

When I replace the `insertSubview:belowSubview:` call with `insertSubview:aboveSubview:`, it works fine (albeit with the white `UIView` showing up above the swiped cell), so it's not a matter of not allocating `_cellBack` properly. I've also tried `insertSubview:atIndex:` and that didn't work either..

What could be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to A) insert your new view BELOW (e.g underneath) the specified cell, so that your new view and the table cell are layered one on top of the other; or are you trying to B) insert a new row for your table, so that if the table had three cells at the beginning after your code runs it would have four?

Comment: I'm trying to add it below the cell. It's not a new row that I'm adding though.

Comment: So could it be that you are successfully adding your subview, but since it is the same size and at the same location as the table cell, you just cannot see it because the table cell is on top of it and completely hiding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that, if I add it to another view, the code works as expected.

Here's where I added it:

```
    _cellBack = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
    _cellBack.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [cell insertSubview:_cellBack belowSubview:cell.contentView];
```

I'm still not sure why the code in the question doesn't work. The `SideSwipeTableView` from [this github account](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes) has code similar to what I had before and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

To make the SideSwipeTableView example work on ios7 & previous, simply change the line to

```
[cell.superview insertSubview:self.sideSwipeView belowSubview:cell];
```

Anything else pushes the back view on top of the cell and you don't get any animation effect, animation happening behind your background cell! To check this change the offset of the cell to less than the full screen to check that your cell is still on the top and background one is really below. From:

```
cell.frame = CGRectMake(direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight ? cellFrame.size.width : -cellFrame.size.width, cellFrame.origin.y, cellFrame.size.width, cellFrame.size.height);
```

to

```
cell.frame = CGRectMake(direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight ? cellFrame.size.width/2 : -cellFrame.size.width/2, cellFrame.origin.y, cellFrame.size.width, cellFrame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView`'s already have the ability to put things behind cells. It's the `backgroundView` of the cell. Why don't you try that instead so you would do the following:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = _cellBack;
```